# bxslider - How to prevent div width of slide box from being set automatically

Tags: bxslider

We will inform you in advance! I'm not good at English, Language skills are also poor. so please understand. hahaha... :)

I'm trying to implement an image slider using bxslider(using cdn). The number of images shown on the screen is two, and I want to implement a slider that moves one image at a time. So I set minSlides and maxSlides to 2.
I didn't get the results I wanted, so I checked the developer tools and found that the width of bx-wrapper > bx-viewport > slide-box > div was set arbitrarily.

So in conclusion, I am curious about how to adjust the width of the automatically set div to fit the size of the image.

style.css

```
.wrap {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.inner {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
max-width: 80%;
}

.slide-box {
display: block;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
text-align: center !important;
}

.slide-box div {
width: auto !important;
display: inline-block !important;
}

.img-certification {
width: 7% !important;
height: 170px !important;
border: 1px solid black;
display: block;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrap" style="margin-top: 3rem;">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="slide-box">
        <div>
                 <img class="img-certification" src="image file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```